# Using SaveFileDialog with ClosedXML

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint-2010, path, savefiledialog

I try to tell you my problem. with `ClosedXML` i have `SaveAs()` method, but when i use `SaveAs(string name)`, it saves my excel document to some strange folder with some strange path. so i've decide to use `savefiledialog` to give user posibility to select folder and name for document. how can i use `savefiledialog` with `closedXML`?

`SaveAs()` also have `SaveAs(Path path)`. Can i use it?

Comment: Does `SaveAs()` have any overloads for you to add a path?

Comment: Yes, it have two overloads - SaveAs(string name) and SaveAs(Path path)

Comment: I don't know for sure, however my guess would be that you could do something like `string path = saveFileDialog.Path` after the user selects the path then use the `SaveAs(name, path)` or however `SaveAs` overloads. It's just a guess though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "strange" folder is the folder your application is running from (since you're not specifying a path).

If you want you can use the SaveFileDialog to get the path and pass it to the SaveAs method.

```
    var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
                             {
                                 Filter = "Excel files|*.xlsx", 
                                 Title = "Save an Excel File"
                             };

    saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(saveFileDialog.FileName))
        workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog.FileName);
```

Comment: Btw, strange path for strange folder is C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv and it's not a folder my application is running from)

Answer (score 0):

```
var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel files|*.xlsx";

//serialVal is name of a variable, not necessary at all if you don't need a specific file name

saveFileDialog.FileName = serialVal; 
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog.FileName);
    workbook.Dispose();
    return;
}
```